# Centring an HTA window

Tags: html, hta

How do I centre an HTA window so that it is in the centre of the screen regardless of the screen resolution of the size of the HTA. I have this:

```
</head>
<script>
Sub DoResize 'Do not use Window_Onload
   window.resizeTo 800,600
   strComputer = "."
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")
   For Each objItem in colItems
       intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
       intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
   Next
   intLeft = (intHorizontal - 800) / 2
   intTop = (intVertical - 600) / 2
   window.moveTo intLeft, intTop
End Sub
DoResize() 'Run the subroutine to position the containing window (your HTA dialog) before the body is rendered.
</script>
<body>
```

But if I change the screen resolution it doesn't work and it resizes the HTA window.

How do I move the HTA to the centre of the screen regardless of the HTA size of screen resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using WMI for this is a bit overkilling. You can use `screen` object instead:

```
window.resizeTo (800, 600);
window.moveTo((screen.width - 800) / 2, (screen.height - 600) / 2);
```

If you want to resize the window at start, put the lines above to a (JS) `script` tag in the `head` section, even before `<hta: application>` tag, or use the code in an event handler or where ever you need it.

If you want to exclude taskbar's height out of the centering area, you can use `screen.availHeight` instead of `screen.height`.

Comment: This resizes the hta though.

Comment: You've to know the size of the window, you can't center a window with unknown size...

Answer (score 2):

```
var winWidth = 800, winHeight = 600;
window.resizeTo(winWidth, winHeight);
window.moveTo((screen.width - winWidth) / 2, (screen.height - winHeight) / 2);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how this solves the question.  For example, where is the mistake in the code.

Comment: Why resize to some other value than in the question?

Answer (score 0):

HTA window

> `

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Operations</title>
    <hta:application id="FileOperationsHTA" 
                     applicationname="FileOperationsHTA" 
                     singleinstance="yes" 
                     maximizebutton="no" 
                     minimizebutton="no" 
                     windowstate="normal" 
                     scroll="no" 
                     navigable="yes" 
                     showintaskbar="no" 
                     contextmenu="no" 
                     selection="no"
    />
</head>


<body onload="showFields()">
    <h1>File Operations</h1>
    <label for="operationCombo">Select operation:</label>
    <select id="operationCombo" onchange="showFields()">
        <option value="">Select an operation</option>
        <option value="move">Move</option>
        <option value="copy">Copy</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
        <option value="newfolder">New Folder</option>
     <option value="rename">Rename</option>
    </select>

    <div id="sourceField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="sourcePath">Source path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sourcePath" />
    </div>

    <div id="destinationField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="destinationPath">Destination path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destinationPath" />
    </div>

    <div id="deleteField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="deletePath">File/Folder to delete:</label>
        <input type="text" id="deletePath" />
    </div>

    <div id="newFolderField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="parentPath">Parent path for new folder:</label>
        <input type="text" id="parentPath" />
        <label for="newFolderName">New folder name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newFolderName" />
    </div>
 <div id="renameField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="sourcePathRename">Source path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sourcePathRename" />
        <label for="destinationPathRename">Destination path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destinationPathRename" />
        <label for="newFileName">New filename:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newFileName" />
    </div>


    <button id="executeButton" onclick="executeOperation()">Execute</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFields() {

           

            var operation = document.getElementById('operationCombo').value;
            var sourceField = document.getElementById('sourceField');
            var destinationField = document.getElementById('destinationField');
            var deleteField = document.getElementById('deleteField');
            var newFolderField = document.getElementById('newFolderField');
        var renameField = document.getElementById('renameField');
            var executeButton = document.getElementById('executeButton');


            sourceField.style.display = 'none';
            destinationField.style.display = 'none';
            deleteField.style.display = 'none';
            newFolderField.style.display = 'none';
            renameField.style.display = 'none';

           

            switch (operation) {
                case 'move':
                    sourceField.style.display = 'block';
                    destinationField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'copy':
                    sourceField.style.display = 'block';
                    destinationField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    deleteField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'newfolder':
                    newFolderField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
         case 'rename':
                    renameField.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('sourcePathRename').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('destinationPathRename').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('newFileName').disabled = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

       function executeOperation() {
            var operation = document.getElementById('operationCombo').value;
            switch (operation) {
                case 'move':
                    var sourcePath = document.getElementById('sourcePath').value;
                    var destinationPath = document.getElementById('destinationPath').value;
                    moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath);
                    break;
                case 'copy':
                    var sourcePath = document.getElementById('sourcePath').value;
                    var destinationPath = document.getElementById('destinationPath').value;
                    copyFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    var deletePath = document.getElementById('deletePath').value;
                    deleteFilesWithWildcard(deletePath);
                    break;
                case 'newfolder':
                    var parentPath = document.getElementById('parentPath').value;
                    var newFolderName = document.getElementById('newFolderName').value;
                    createNewFolder(parentPath, newFolderName);
                    break;
         case 'rename':
                    var sourcePathRename = document.getElementById('sourcePathRename').value;
                    var destinationPathRename = document.getElementById('destinationPathRename').value;
                    var newFileName = document.getElementById('newFileName').value;
                    renameFile(sourcePathRename, destinationPathRename, newFileName);
                    break;
            }
        }

function renameFile(sourcePath, destinationPath, newFileName) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            if (fso.FileExists(sourcePath)) {
                try {
                    fso.MoveFile(sourcePath, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, newFileName));
                    alert('Rename operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error renaming file: ' + e.message);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Source file not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            var sourceFile = fso.BuildPath(parentFolder, file.Name);
                            var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                            fso.MoveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                            fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                            moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error moving files/folders with wildcard.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Parent path not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                fso.MoveFile(file.Path, destinationFile);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }

        function copyFiles(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var folder = fso.GetFolder(sourcePath);

            if (fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                try {
                    copyFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath);
                    alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource Path: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination Path: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error copying files/folders.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Destination path not found.');
            }
        }

        function copyFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                fso.CopyFile(file.Path, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name), true);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                copyFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }

 function moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            var sourceFile = fso.BuildPath(parentFolder, file.Name);
                            var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                            fso.MoveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                            fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                            moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error moving files/folders with wildcard.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Parent path not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                fso.MoveFile(file.Path, destinationFile);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }




    


    function copyFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (fso.FileExists(sourcePath)) {
            // Source path is a single file
            var sourceFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var sourceFileName = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);

            if (fso.FileExists(destinationPath)) {
                // Destination path includes a filename, create a new folder in the destination path
                var destinationParentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(destinationPath);
                var newFolderName = fso.GetBaseName(destinationPath);
                destinationPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationParentFolder, newFolderName);
            } else if (!fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                // Destination folder does not exist, create it
                fso.CreateFolder(destinationPath);
            }

            // Perform the copy operation
            fso.CopyFile(sourcePath, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, sourceFileName));
            alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
        } else if (fso.FolderExists(sourcePath)) {
            // Source path is a folder
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    // Collect files and folders matching the wildcard
                    var filesToCopy = [];
                    var foldersToCopy = [];

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            filesToCopy.push(file);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            foldersToCopy.push(subFolder);
                        }
                    }

                    // Perform the copy operation
                    if (!fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                        // Destination folder does not exist, create it
                        fso.CreateFolder(destinationPath);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < filesToCopy.length; i++) {
                        var file = filesToCopy[i];
                        file.Copy(fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name));
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < foldersToCopy.length; i++) {
                        var folder = foldersToCopy[i];
                        copyFolderRecursive(folder, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, folder.Name));
                    }

                    alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error copying files/folders with wildcard: ' + e.message);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Source parent path not found.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Source path not found.');
        }
    }

  







  
    function copyFolderRecursive(sourceFolder, destinationFolder) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        fso.CreateFolder(destinationFolder);

        var files = new Enumerator(sourceFolder.Files);
        var subFolders = new Enumerator(sourceFolder.SubFolders);

        for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
            var file = files.item();
            file.Copy(fso.BuildPath(destinationFolder, file.Name));
        }

        for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            copyFolderRecursive(subFolder, fso.BuildPath(destinationFolder, subFolder.Name));
        }
    }

 

function createNewFolder(parentPath, newFolderName) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fullPath = fso.BuildPath(parentPath, newFolderName);

            try {
                fso.CreateFolder(fullPath);
                alert('New folder created successfully.\nPath: ' + fullPath);
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Error creating new folder: ' + e.message);
            }
        }






    function deleteFilesWithWildcard(deletePath) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(deletePath);
        var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(deletePath);
        var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

        if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
            try {
                var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                // Collect files and folders matching the wildcard
                var filesToDelete = [];
                var foldersToDelete = [];

                for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                    var file = files.item();
                    if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                        filesToDelete.push(file);
                    }
                }

                for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                    var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                    if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                        foldersToDelete.push(subFolder);
                    }
                }

                // Delete files
                for (var i = 0; i < filesToDelete.length; i++) {
                    filesToDelete[i].Delete();
                }

                // Delete folders
                for (var i = 0; i < foldersToDelete.length; i++) {
                    deleteFolderRecursive(foldersToDelete[i]);
                }

                alert('Delete operation executed.\nPath: ' + deletePath);
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Error deleting files/folders with wildcard: ' + e.message);
            }
        } else {
            alert('Parent path not found.');
        }
    }

    function deleteFolderRecursive(folder) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

        for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            deleteFolderRecursive(subFolder);
        }

        fso.DeleteFolder(folder.Path);
    }




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`